# Regex Replace pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need the regular expression to replace using following rule:

- Any integer present before `.` then no take place.
- If no integer present before `.` then that should be replace.

  $input = (contain anything characters, symbols, numbers, floats etc)

Example:

```
$myString = "Example 1.58 Stack.68";
```

Output should be

```
Example 1.58 Stack,68
```

Comment: Please specify the logic of your replace

Comment: Why not replace the first `.` by a `,` too?

Comment: `Segmentation fault: login unknown`

Comment: Any integer present before '.' then no take place. 
and
if no integer present before '.' then that should be replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#(?<!\d)\.#',',',$myString)
```

Comment: http://phpresult.com

try ur code here its not working...

Comment: @Codesen http://regexr.com?35bt8

Comment: try this post ur output <?php

echo preg_replace('#(?<!\d)\.#',',','Example 1.38 Test.56');


?>

Comment: @Codesen Your testing engine is crap, use http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/